# Laravel 5.2 : `php artisan migrate` 's error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 ,there is an error when I run `php artisan migrate`,as follows:

**2016_06_12_134655_create_categories_table.php**

```
public function up() {
   Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {

   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('category');
   $table->timestamps();

   });
}
```

**2016_06_12_134659_create_goods_table.php**

```
public function up() {
   Schema::create('goods', function(Blueprint $table) {

   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('unit_price');
   $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
   $table->tinyInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
   $table->timestamps();

   });
}
```

**$php artisan migrate**

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: It seems that your `category_id` as no reference. Your categories table should be first.

Answer (score 1):

It might be complaining about your use of `tinyInteger` on `category_id`, try setting it to `integer` as well - assuming your categories table exists. If it does not, you need to make sure any migrations with a foreign key constraint have their related tables migrated before them. Without seeing your categories table, I might wonder whether the datatype for your `id` is the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced table `categories` has a primary key of type int. Keep the same in the referencing column `category_id` if You want to keep foreign key constraints, defined in line:

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use primary key `$table->Increments('id');`

you should use `Integer` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->tinyIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedTinyInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedTinyInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->smallIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedSmallInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedSmallInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->mediumIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedMediumInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedMediumInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```